# Is someone input type datetime local working in FireFox?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, firefox

I'm try to implement a Datetime-local in Firefox but don't work, someone have an solution for this?, or a js that can ilustrate something similar like datetime-local?

This is like look in FireFox :

[image]

I only want to found a solution for this, that the user can write a Date-time on input

Answer (score 0):

I have totally scrapped the idea of using datetime-local because the users complained when using Firefox and Safari. I have spent all this week and merged the JQuery ui Datepicker with the clocklet time picker to create a nice datetime picker.
I have a solution that is working great for my application. The only drawback is that you can't edit the final datetime directly in a textbox, you must use the date and time buttons provided. My users don't find this to be a drawback at all and they can set datetime much faster than datetime-local.

This works on Windows and Mac; Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Firefox Developer Edition, Opera and Safari.

This example shows 2 instances, start and end times.

Operation is straight forward, select date then select time and press enter.

```js
  (function() {

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // Start Datetime
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    $("#inputStartDate").datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/39_Calendar-20.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      minDate: 0,
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var inputEvent = new Event('input', {
          bubbles: true
        });
        document.getElementById("inputStartDate").dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
      }
    });

    const divStartDatetime = document.querySelector('#divStartDatetime');

    const inputStartClock = document.querySelector('#inputStartClock');
    if (inputStartClock.value === '') {
      inputStartClock.value = getTimeFromDate(new Date());
    }

    const inputStartDate = document.querySelector('#inputStartDate');
    if (inputStartDate.value === '') {
      inputStartDate.value = new Date();
    }

    divStartDatetime.innerHTML = formatDisplayDateTime(inputStartDate, inputStartClock);

    var inputStartClocklet = document.querySelector('#inputStartClock');

    document.getElementById("inputStartDate").addEventListener('input', function(event) {
      divStartDatetime.innerHTML = formatDisplayDateTime(inputStartDate, inputStartClock);
      inputStartClocklet.focus();
    });

    var startTimeIcon = document.querySelector('#startTimeIcon');
    startTimeIcon.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      inputStartClocklet.focus();
    });

    inputStartClocklet.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
      divStartDatetime.innerHTML = formatDisplayDateTime(inputStartDate, inputStartClock);
    });

    inputStartClocklet.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      document.querySelector('.timeCloseHidden').focus();
    });

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // End Datetime
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    $("#inputEndDate").datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/39_Calendar-20.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      minDate: 0,
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var inputEvent = new Event('input', {
          bubbles: true
        });
        document.getElementById("inputEndDate").dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
      }
    });

    const divEndDatetime = document.querySelector('#divEndDatetime');

    const inputEndClock = document.querySelector('#inputEndClock');
    if (inputEndClock.value === '') {
      inputEndClock.value = '23:59';
    }

    const inputEndDate = document.querySelector('#inputEndDate');
    if (inputEndDate.value === '') {
      inputEndDate.value = new Date();
    }

    divEndDatetime.innerHTML = formatDisplayDateTime(inputEndDate, inputEndClock);

    var inputEndClocklet = document.querySelector('#inputEndClock');

    document.getElementById("inputEndDate").addEventListener('input', function(event) {
      divEndDatetime.innerHTML = formatDisplayDateTime(inputEndDate, inputEndClock);
      inputEndClocklet.focus();
    });

    var endTimeIcon = document.querySelector('#endTimeIcon');
    endTimeIcon.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      inputEndClocklet.focus();
    });

    inputEndClocklet.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
      divEndDatetime.innerHTML = formatDisplayDateTime(inputEndDate, inputEndClock);
    });

    inputEndClocklet.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      document.querySelector('.timeCloseHidden').focus();
    });

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // Common Functions
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    function formatDisplayDateTime(theDate, theTime) {
      return getDateFromDate(new Date(theDate.value)) + " " + formatAMPM(new Date('01/01/1970 ' + theTime.value));
    }

    function getTimeFromDate(dateToConvert) {
      var hour = dateToConvert.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      var minute = dateToConvert.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      return hour + ':' + minute;
    }

    function getDateFromDate(dateToConvert) {
      var yyyy = dateToConvert.getFullYear();
      var month = (dateToConvert.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
      var day = dateToConvert.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      return month + '/' + day + '/' + yyyy;
    }

    function formatAMPM(date) {
      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
      hours = hours % 12;
      hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
      return hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ' ' + ampm;
    }

  })();
```

```css
    .timeCloseHidden {
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
      border: none;
      background: none;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0 px;
      position: absolute;
      top: -100px;
    }

    .input_icon {
      font-size: 20px;
      float: right;
      margin: 5px;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .inputContainer {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      max-width: 276px;
      max-width: 276px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .input_datetime {
      border: none;
      width: 0px;
      opacity: 0.0;
    }

    .input_datetime_mask {
      width: 140px;
    }

    .inputStartDateInstanceContainer,
    .inputEDateInstanceContainer {
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .date_label {
      margin: 2px;
      width: 75px;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .clocklet-options-2 {
      font-family: "Frank Ruhl Libre", serif;
      font-weight: 500;
    }

    #inputStartClock,
    #inputEndClock {
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      display: block;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      border: none;
      opacity: 0.0;
      width: 0px;
    }

    #startTimeIcon,
    #endTimeIcon {
      background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/52_Clock-20.png);
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      margin-left: -10px;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clocklet@0.3.0/css/clocklet.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clocklet@0.3.0"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="timeCloseHidden"></button>

    <div id="startDateContainer" class="startDateContainer">
      <div class="inputContainer">
        <span class="date_label">Start Date: </span>
        <div id="divStartDatetime" class="input_datetime_mask"></div>
        <input type="text" id="inputStartDate" class="input_datetime" />
        <div class="inputStartDateInstanceContainer">
          <input id="inputStartClock" class="clocklet-events" data-clocklet="class-name: clocklet-options-2; format: hh:mm a; alignment: right; append-to: parent;" placeholder="hh:mm am">
        </div>
        <div id="startTimeIcon"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="endDateContainer" class="endDateContainer">
      <div class="inputContainer">
        <span class="date_label">End Date: </span>
        <div id="divEndDatetime" class="input_datetime_mask"></div>
        <input type="text" id="inputEndDate" class="input_datetime" />
        <div class="inputEndDateInstanceContainer">
          <input id="inputEndClock" class="clocklet-events" data-clocklet="class-name: clocklet-options-2; format: hh:mm a; alignment: right; append-to: parent;" placeholder="hh:mm am">
        </div>
        <div id="endTimeIcon"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Gee, you are 100% correct. FireFox is a absolute mess and a big train falling off the tracks in a HUGE ball of flames.

Given this simple markup:

```
        <div style="float: left">
            <h3>TextMode="Date"</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyDate" runat="server"
                TextMode="Date">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:45px">
            <h3>TextMode="Time"</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTime" runat="server"
                TextMode="Time">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:35px">
            <h3>TextMode="DateTimeLocal"</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyDTime" runat="server"
                TextMode="DateTimeLocal">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
```

In Edge (new Chrome version), and in Google Chrome, we get/see this:

[image]

As you can see, for Date, Time, and DateTime, BOTH Edge and Google Chrome browsers work fine.

However, FireFox falls down, does not work, and creates a huge ball of flames in failure:

WOW! I've always been a big fan of Firefox, but this is a HUGE deal breaker for the whole asp.net community.

[image]

So, as above shows, with FireFox, then the data picker does work, but the time picker does not pop a dialog (it DOES show a input mask). And the Date+time picker fails in a huge ball of flames.

So, there are two solutions I can think of:

One: simple warn and tell users not to use FireFox, since it simple fails, does not work, and can't do simple web based tasks like picking a time.

Two: Adopt a 3rd party jQuery or bootstrap library that allows some kind of pop dialog or time picker. There are many to choose from, but attempts to use a input control on a form with a automatic time picker with FireFox is simply not an option at this point in time.

So, FireFox simply does not work, can't be used, or as noted, if you want to support FireFox, then you have to introduce a 3rd party time picker, as the built in browser based ones can't be used.

There are endless choices of sample JavaScript libraries, but Firefox out of the box is not such a valid choice. You need to adopt 3rd party code for this to work.

Comment: Yes i know, i just have to use a library for this work, if someone want to know wwhat library i used is this : https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/

Comment: I had not realized this issue, and it hurts, since I'm a big fan of FireFox.  I don't have any time picking in my sites, but I will in the future, and thus this post has saved me from grief down the road. So, yes, it looks like we have to adopt a 3rd party library.